# 'getfattr' to list all attributes of the files in the folder

Tags: attributes

I'm having minor trouble with getting my head around it cause none of the tried commands does not display anything. I would like to check file attributes of the every file in the folder (including subfolders and so on).

Let's assume I'm having a path: `mainfolder/subfolder/file.txt` - if I submit it directly like this:

```
getfattr -d /mnt/Users/Family/Documents/credentials.txt
```

It does the job and returns that there is some attribute. But now I'd like to search a whole folder like that for every file in every folder and subfolder. So I tried some of the ways of getting it but these returned nothing for me:

```
getfattr -d -m ^ -R -- <filename or directory>
getfattr -m - $your_path_or_file_name
```

I'm not even sure if it's possible to list attributes like that in a recursive way. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You can dump them and then use awk

```
getfattr --dump * > xfatrrts.txt
```

[Here](https://linux-user.gr/t/ektetamenes-idiothtes-archeiwn/2379) you will find some tricks (in Greek).